# What is the analogue for Scanner/System.in if I want to do the output?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, system.out, system.in

If I use the Scanner type for reading System.out, I can easily switch from System.in to some file and thus I can test the methods working with the input.

```
    String line;

       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  // reading from the command line
    
    // or
 
       File file = new File(someFileName);   
       in = new Scanner(file);              // reading from the file

    System.out.print("Type something: ");
    line = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You said: " + line);
```

But what type can I use for the same switch for the output, if I want my methods to alternatively write to a file or to System.out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out` is a `PrintStream`. You can always create your own PrintStream that writes to a file.

```
PrintStream out = System.out;
out.print("Write to console");
out = new PrintStream(new File("path"));
out.print("Write to file");
```

Just be careful.`System.out` shouldn't be closed while a `PrintStream` created from a file should be closed.

Comment: It nicely works. Upvoting... Sorry for the late reaction - I couldn't check it fast.